# Package Import woes in Python

Tags: python, import, package

My structure is thus:

```
companynamespace/
  __init__.py
  projectpackage/
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
```

`companynamespace/__init__.py` is empty

`projectpackage/__init__.py` has this line:

```
import companynamespace.projectpackage.somemodule as module_shortname
```

When I open up a python console and type `import companynamespace.projectpackage` (PYTHONPATH is set correctly for this), I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'projectpackage'` on the `import companynamespace.projectpackage.somemodule as module_shortname` line. If I remove the `as module_shortname` part (and make all the requisite substitutions in the rest of the file), everything imports correctly.

Can anyone tell me why this is? My Google-Fu fails me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for absolute import in `projectpackage/__init__.py`, do relative one

```
import somemodule as module_shortname
```

The way you're doing it (with absolute import), would lead to circular import, which don't work very well in Python. When you're importing module, you're also calling `__init__.py` of parent modules. In your case, with absolute import you're also calling `projectpackage/__init__.py` in `projectpackage/__init__.py`.

Comment: The diagnosis (i.e. a circular import problem) is correct, but the explanation and suggested resolution aren't quite right. When `projectpackage/__init__.py` is executed, the `projectpackage` attribute in `companynamespace` is not yet set, hence the specific error that is raised. For current Python, an explicit relative import (`from . import somemodule`) is a better choice than relying on an implicit relative import.

Comment: Thanks a mil, I'd figured a circular import issue, but had no idea what functionality Python had to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the [PEP 221](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) your code seems to be legitimate. It could be a bug. The following workaround, which is equivalent of that expression, works for me (Python 2.6.6):

```
from companynamespace.projectpackage import somemodule as module_shortname
```

Hope it helps.